# My doctest does not return correctly. What am I doing wrong

Tags: elixir, doctest

I have the following files. If you look in app.ex the doctest says 2 + 2 is 3. 
I am intentionally trying to make it fail.

**app.ex**

```
defmodule App do
     @doc """
      Adds two numbers

      ## Examples

        iex> App.add(2, 2)
        3

      """
    def add(a,b) do
      a + b
    end


end
```

**app_test.exs**

```
defmodule AppTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  doctest App
end
```

In the console I type: `mix test` and the result is:

```
Finished in 0.01 seconds
0 failures

Randomized with seed 547000
```

Comment: This might seem a bit silly, but I think, for examples to be executed by Doctest, the `iex>` block has to be indebted with **4** spaces, not **2**. Could you give it a try?

Comment: FYI In Elixir 1.3.4, you can just copy-paste the above code and it works. It seems this limitation was removed recently.

Comment: I'll add this as an answer then! Glad I could help @William!

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be in formatting of your `@doc`. I think, the examples to be properly parsed and executed by Doctest, have to be indented with **4** spaces.

I'm pasting your code here with updated formatting for reference:

```
defmodule App do
  @doc """
  Adds two numbers

  ## Examples

      iex> App.add(2, 2)
      3

  """
  def add(a,b) do
    a + b
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that mix is not finding any test cases at all, otherwise you would get the message `12 tests, 0 failures` instead of just `0 failures`

This probably happens because of the non-standard naming of your test file. In Elixir, test files must end with `*_test.exs`, you used `*.text.exs` (maybe a typo).

If you rename your test to `test/app_test.exs` it should work just fine.

Comment: The test file is named with an underscore. I made a mistype in the stackoverflow query

Comment: And is  `text` also a typo?

Comment: :) Yes, it was.